# Android exception in sql query that runs fines in DB Browser

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite

When running the following query on Android

```
select * 
from EICRChecklistItems 
where (Sect, S_Sect, SS_Sect) in (
  select Sect, S_Sect, SS_Sect 
  from EICRCheckList 
  where Version=2018 
  order by id
) 
order by id
```

I get the exception:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code
> 1)

Columns `Sect`, `S_Sect` and `SS_Sect` are all defined as `integer`.

But when running on DB Browser against a copy of the same database it executes correctly

Any pointers as to what may be causing this would be greatly appreciated.

```
private var EICR_CHECK_ITEMS_TABLE = "EICRChecklistItems"
private var EICR_CHECKLIST_TABLE = "EICRCheckList"
val cursor1: Cursor = writableDatabase.rawQuery(
            "select * from $EICR_CHECK_ITEMS_TABLE where (Sect, S_Sect, SS_Sect) in (select Sect, S_Sect, SS_Sect from $EICR_CHECKLIST_TABLE where Version='2018' order by id) order by id",  null)
```

Comment: Post the actual code that executes this query. As it is the query is fine. Also are you sure that the database that you use in Android is an exact copy of the database that DB Browser uses?

Comment: I've updated the question with the code used to execute the query, Yes the database is an exact copy, I have used android studio to download the database from the device

Comment: One more thing to check is the version of SQLite. Check the result of `select sqlite_version();` Your query uses ROW VALUES: https://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html so the version must be at least 3.15.0

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, you are correct, the sqlite version in use on my device, 3.8.6 and as such does not support ROW VALUES. If you would like post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your SQLite's version is prior to 3.15.0 and you can't use [`ROW VALUES`](https://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html), you can write your query with `EXISTS` instead of the operator `IN`:

```
SELECT ei.* 
FROM EICRChecklistItems ei 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM EICRCheckList el
  WHERE el.Version = 2018
  AND el.Sect = ei.Sect AND el.S_Sect = ei.S_Sect AND el.SS_Sect = ei.SS_Sect
)
ORDER BY ei.id
```

Note that the `ORDER BY` clause that you had inside the subquery in your code is actually useless.